# Failsafe : Execute a void method and return result based on success/failure

Tags: java, retrypolicy, java-failsafe

I am using `Failsafe` framework ([link](https://jodah.net/failsafe/)) to execute a method. My use case is to execute a `void` method x number of times and return `success` or `failure` based on the execution result. Below is how my (pseudo) code looks like:

```
public void methodThatNeedsToExecute(){..}

public String failsafeWrapper(){
    RetryPolicy<String> retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<>().withMaxRetries(50);
    return Failsafe.with(retryPolicy)
        .onSuccess(return "success") // how to do this?
        .onFailure(return "failure") //how to do this?
        .get(() -> methodThatNeedsToExecute()); //this won't work

}
```

I can use `run` method of `Failsafe` to execute my void method (i.e. `methodThatNeedsToExecute()`). However, how can I return something based on how execution with retries goes?

Comment: how do you decide whether it is successful or not?

Comment: If I run out of retries, it is a failure and if any of the exectution succeeds, it's success.